# how to make the quiz's hint like a hangman game in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

What I want to make :

If the correct answer is :

> Hello

then the hint is

> _ e_ _o

**condition**

1. length of the answer is vary.
2. quantity of hidden character is random.

**here's what I tried:**

```js
function makeHint(string) {
    const indexOne = _.random(0, string.length);
    const indexTwo = _.random(0, string.length);
    const indexThree = _.random(0, string.length);

    const myArray = string.split('');
    const charOne = myArray.splice(indexOne, 1, myArray[indexOne]);
    const charTwo = myArray.splice(indexOne, 1, myArray[indexTwo]);
    const charThree = myArray.splice(indexOne, 1, myArray[indexThree]);

    return myArray
      .map((char) => '_')
      .splice(indexOne, 1, charOne)
      .splice(indexTwo, 1, charTwo)
      .splice(indexThree, 1, charThree)
      .join(' ');
  }
```

my code look so bad, and it did NOT work :(
I ablsolute have no idea.
what should I fix?

thank you.

Comment: I would do this using an array of guessed characters. You could then split the string into a character array and check if each of the characters appears in the array. If the character has been guessed then show the character if not show "_". It might be more performant to use an associative array / map instead of a normal array for the guessed characters. `const word = 'hello'; const guessChars = ['e','o']; word.split('').map(c => guessChars.includes(c) ? c : '_').join(' ');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

An issue I see is that your solution doesn't handle dynamic hint creation, i.e. you've hardcoded how many you want. A second issue is that none of your random character selections are isolated from any other selection.

## Solution

I suggest you consume a `string` and a `hintsNumber` value to dynamically create the hints. Start with a copy of the string already masked out, and iterate until you've replaced the appropriate number of hints.

```
const makeHint = (string, hints = 3) => {
  let hintString = string.replaceAll(/./g, "_");
  let hintsRemaining = hints;

  while (hintsRemaining) {
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * hintString.length);
    if (hintString.charAt(i) === "_") {
      hintString =
        hintString.substring(0, i) +
        string.charAt(i) +
        hintString.substring(i + 1);
      hintsRemaining--;
    }
  }
  return hintString;
};
```

```js
const makeHint = (string, hints = 3) => {
  let hintString = string.replaceAll(/./g, "_");
  let hintsRemaining = hints;

  while (hintsRemaining) {
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * hintString.length);
    if (hintString.charAt(i) === "_") {
      hintString =
        hintString.substring(0, i) +
        string.charAt(i) +
        hintString.substring(i + 1);
      hintsRemaining--;
    }
  }
  return hintString;
};

console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 0));
console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 1));
console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 2));
console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 3));
console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 4));
console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 5));
```

## Improved Algorithm

Looking at this I realized it can be improved to remove the inner copy loop, i.e. moves from something around `O(n^2)` closer to `O(n)` complexity. Create an array of the character and just update the indices and return a rejoined string.

```
const makeHint = (string, hints = 3) => {
  const hintString = Array(string.length).fill("_");
  let hintsRemaining = hints;

  while (hintsRemaining) {
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * hintString.length);
    if (hintString[i] === "_") {
      hintString[i] = string.charAt(i);
      hintsRemaining--;
    }
  }
  return hintString.join('');
};
```

```js
const makeHint = (string, hints = 3) => {
  const hintString = Array(string.length).fill("_");
  let hintsRemaining = hints;

  while (hintsRemaining) {
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * hintString.length);
    if (hintString[i] === "_") {
      hintString[i] = string.charAt(i);
      hintsRemaining--;
    }
  }
  return hintString.join('');
};

console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 0));
console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 1));
console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 2));
console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 3));
console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 4));
console.log(makeHint("someBigWord", 5));
```